# Use maps FragmentActivity inside of FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I know there are a few similar questions out there to this, but I haven't seen one with this exact issue. I have a `ViewPager` and I have *MapsActivity.java* that extends `FragmentActivity`. One tab I want to be a `listView` the other tab will be the map.

Currently the adapter accepts `Fragment` but not `FragmentActivity` which is what the map is. I need to know the best way, given my current setup how to get the Map inside of the tab. It works on its own outside oft the tabs in its own activity, but that isn't where I want it.

I do not want to use a `MapView` because they are old. I am trying to be as modern as possible with my development.

Here is the adapter and where I set up the `ViewPager` inside of *MainActivity.java*:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ListFragment(), "Events");
    adapter.addFragment(new ListFragment(), "Map");
    //where I want to add the MapsActivity^
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

And here is the barebones *MapsActivity.java* I want to get inside of the tab:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

I tried changing the *ListFragment.java* lass from just extending `Fragment` to `FragmentActivity` and then the type that the adapter worked with. As well as `List<FragmentActivity> mFragments` but I ran into trouble with the `getItem()`.

Once I made the above changes like so:

```
    @Override
    public FragmentActivity getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }
```

There was a conflict with incompatible types. `getItem(position)` from *...MainActivity.Adapter* clashes with `getItem(position)` from *...support.FragmentPagerAdapter*.

Please show/advise me in the best way to get this maps FragmentActivity inside of this tab.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an Activity in a ViewPager. An Activity can contain Views, but Views cannot contain Activities.

The first step is to completely encapsulate your maps code within a fragment. The good news is you are very close- you have a `MapFragment` and the only thing you are really doing in your Activity is adding a marker.

Move the marker code into a Fragment that extends `MapFragment`, and use your `MapFragment` in your `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and bear with me since I'm still new to maps. So you are suggesting I create a new class, _Map.java_ for example. Inside of that class I'd need `onCreate` etc, and then all of the map functions would take place in there? Then back inside of _MapsActivity.java_ I would ditch the `setUpMap` and `setUpMapIfNeeded` methods, but leave the `onCreate` / `onResume` methods?

Comment: Almost- I'm saying completely ditch the `MapsActivity`, since you can't use it in your ViewPager. You are essentially replacing your `MapsActivity` with a new class that extends `MapFragment`,

Comment: Okay, When I try this I and try and add `adapter.addFragment(new MapFrag(), "Map")` I get an error saying that it "Found `com.blah.MapFrag` but required `android.support.v4.ap.Fragment`"

Comment: If you are using support library Fragments, you will need to extend `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`.

Comment: Yeah I figured that much out. I changed all of the necessary things like inside of the xml for the fragment. I also had to change the _MapFrag.java_ to extend `Fragment` because that's what the adapter accepted. After that the application just crashed on launch.